# URLs with variable query strings and cache

Tags: rest, http, caching

I am developing a media server, the basic functionality is to serve an image, which is done the following way

```
/media/:id
```

where :id is the id of the image.

You may want to ask for a specific size, with some rules I will provide.

Eg:

```
/media/:id/50x50
/media/:id?witdh=50&height=50
```

Question: Which option do you think is better? I believe the second one to be more RESTful and beautiful, but we will be using a CDN and varnish for cache, so if we get

```
/media/:id?width=50&height=50
```

or

```
/media/:id?height=50&width=50
```

we will have 2 hits when we should have 1

Any advice?

Comment: Sounds to me like you can see the exact risk you take if you go with query string parameters, rather than a fixed path component. Now the question is, is that risk acceptable, or too high?

Comment: Using the query parameters suggests to me that `?height=49&width=51` would also be valid. The `50x50` path segment doesn't give this suggestion. How free are your users in choosing image size?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau they can choose whatever size they want in any of the 2 ways

Comment: @SeanMcMillan yep, wanted to see if someone had a solution because the correct way IMO is query string, maybe sorting the query string parameters in akamai and varnish

Comment: Matrix parameters are similar to query parameters but should result in a cacheable response. Maybe change query with matrix parameters?

Answer (score 1):

According to URI standard the path should contain the hierarchical components and the query should contain the non-hierarchical components of the URI. But it can be subjective what is hierarchical and what non-hierarchical.

By developing a REST client these URLs mean nothing, because they follow hyperlinks and check link relations or other additional meta-data. (aka uniform interface / HATEOAS constraint)

If you cannot cache one of them, then you should choose the other one. Note: you always have to send cache headers. (aka cache constraint)